# Фиксация ориентации в Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c

Пишу приложение в последней версии Xcode для iPad с версией iOS 5.1. Для всех view нужно выставить фиксированное значение ориентации UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft. В сториборде установил значения landscape для scene's. В -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: пишу

```
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

После того, как я делаю билд, симулятор открывается в portait и так же и выглядит UI, при имитации поворота устройства все поворачивается (то есть фиксируется в portrait-режиме, а нужно в landscape). Скрины в билдере и на симуляторе:

[image]

[image]

В симуляторе, в схеме и в deplyment target выставлена 5.1. Как решить задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось неожиданно. Заказчик заявил что приложение для шестой оси, методы были переписаны и с методами для шестой все работает нормально

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто на самом деле)
В Xcode выделяете проект(в менюшке слева, название проекта), появляется меню справа, в нем выбираете targets(название прокта), в появившемся меню выбираете Supported Interface Orientation, выбираете поддерживаемые ориентации экрана. Какие выберите такие и будут поддерживаться.

Comment: Выбрал единственную нужную ориентацию, теперь симулятор запускается в ней, но приложение "лежит на боку" как будто приваязано к портретной ориентации. Не пойму как происходит привязка к портретному режиму и как ее убрать

Comment: может попробовать закомментить -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation в контроллере и другие методы которые с ориентацией связаны? может поможет, попробуйте.

Comment: Попробовал, но непонятным образом через раз показывает то нормально то опять "на боку". Пока не понимаю от чего это зависит